# HDMI to DisplayPort MST splitter, possible to support MST?

Tags: hdmi, displayport, mst

Trying to figure out if a Hmdi male to Displayport female adapter would work on a DisplayPort MST splitter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DisplayPorts backward compatibility with DVI and HDMI works from the source device or from MST hubs but may not work from daisy chained devices.

Adapters for converting HDMI into DisplayPort are active converters because HDMI does not have built in compatibility with DisplayPort while DisplayPort does. Such an active device should work fine with MST but make sure it fully supports DHCP if you want it to work in all use cases.